# FadeIn/FadeOut effects for multiple date sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, slider, date-range

I'm using [jQDateRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html) in my project to enable users to choose flight dates. Here is an example: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4YKN/).
In case I'm using multiple sliders without any effects it works perfect. But when I'm trying to enable fadeIn/fadeOut for this elements it works wrong. I've reproduced this issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LDn6P/). 

HTML:

```
<button id="text">Show second slider</button>
<div id="first">
    <div id="slider1"></div>
</div>
<div id="second"  style="display:none;">
    <div id="slider2"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById("text");
el.onclick = function(){$('#first').fadeOut('slow', function(){$('#second').fadeIn('slow');});};
$("#slider1").dateRangeSlider({   
bounds: {
    min: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2012, 11, 31, 12, 59, 59)
},
defaultValues: {
    min: new Date(2012, 1, 10),
    max: new Date(2012, 4, 22)
}
});
$("#slider2").dateRangeSlider({   
bounds: {
    min: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2012, 11, 31, 12, 59, 59)
},
defaultValues: {
    min: new Date(2012, 1, 10),
    max: new Date(2012, 4, 22)
}
});
```

Second slider doesn't want to appear in a proper format with a ruler. Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me when the initialization of the second slider is done in the callback of `fadeOut()`: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDn6P/1/) Can't explain why, though...